# How to unshelve another developer's changes that include dlls or other binaries?

Tags: dll, tfs, nuget, unshelve

Using Team Foundation Server 2010 I am trying to unshelve a series of changes made by another developer on my team. This shelve set includes some Nuget packages which include dlls. I am receiving multiple errors along the lines of:

> The item $/file/path/some.dll is locked for check-out by USER in workspace MACHINENAME.

In 2008 Mac Noland asserted in his blog post [*Unshelving files that have File Merging disabled*](http://team-foundation-server.blogspot.com/2008/01/unshelving-files-that-have-file-merging.html) that this error is caused by having file merging being disabled. Which makes good sense to have file merges disabled for binaries. Based on the error I am assuming that TFS 2010 is still utilizing the merge utility when unshelving (makes sense as to why). That said I do not want to enable file merging for dll files.

Unfortunately, understanding what is going on and fixing it are two different things. In TFS is there a way to unshelve binary files which were shelved by a different user?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the user created the shelveset, but left everything checked out locally, you will receive this error. Since TFS usually allows only a single checkout for binary files, a shelveset can't be unshelved if it contains a binary file which is locked by another user.

You can attempt to unlock the file with the following command -

```
tf lock itemspec /lock:none /workspace:OtherUsersWorkspace
```

You should be able to determine the workspace from the error message, and you'll also need to specify the user - /workspace:WORKSPACE;userid

Comment: I am sure we need to execute this in command prompt. But what location. Can you please give a full good example/

Comment: @ziggler You should be able to include the /server option in the above command. i.e.
`tf lock itemspec /lock:none /workspace:OtherUsersWOrkspace /server:TFSServerURL`

Comment: @dam - I was looking for replies like we need to execute those commands at visual studio command prompt and we need to move to folder/file location like in my case D:\TFS\Source\Development\Cars and then run tf commands.

Answer (score 1):

In my case my source code is located at below location in my work station

D:\TFS\Source\Development\Cars.

I opened **Visual Studio Command Prompt** under Visual Studio Tools and **ran it as Administrator**.

I changed my command prompt to move to

D:\TFS\Source\Development\Cars

Executed below line

D:\TFS\Source\Development\Cars> tf **lock** HE/* **/lock:none** /workspace:**zigglerworkspace**  /login:**ziggler** /collection:**ziggler1pxtfs01\WebProjects**

zigglerworkspace - my workspace name

ziggler - my user name

ziggler1pxtfs01\WebProjects - TFS server url

This released locks on all files and folders under HE folder which is located at

D:\TFS\Source\Development\Cars\HE

Answer (score 1):

1. Install Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010 Power Tools
2. Add `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010 Power Tools` to your system path
3. cd c:[some location]\"destination workspace"
4. `tfpt unshelve /migrate "shelveset name";otherUserName /source:"$/ProjectName/Main/Source" /target:"$/ProjectName/Main/Target"`